# Attaching multiple covariates to ggplot scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm producing a plot like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

data.dist = matrix(
  c(10, -10, 10, -10, 10, -10, 10, -10, 10),
  nrow=3,
  ncol=3,
  byrow = TRUE)

hc <- agnes(dist(data.dist), method = "ward", diss = TRUE)
cluster <- cutree(hc, k=2)
xy <- data.frame(cmdscale(dist(data.dist)), factor(cluster))
names(xy) <- c("x", "y", "cluster")
xy$model <- rownames(xy)

ggplot(xy, aes(x, y)) + geom_point(aes(colour=cluster), size=3)
```

Which gives me:

[image]

However, let's say I want to attach another covariate, say a binary variable `c(1, 0, 1)` to the data and display all `1` using one symbol (say an X) and all `0` using another symbol (say a dot). How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Map the `shape` aesthetic to your covariate. I suggest you study some ggplot2 tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xy<-data.frame(x=rnorm(3),y=rnorm(3),cluster=as.factor(c(1,0,1)),another=as.factor(c(1,1,0)) )
ggplot(xy, aes(x, y,shape=another)) + geom_point(aes(colour=cluster), size=3)
```